# Where I can find ETL  test error messages?

Tags: etl, message, standards

I need to write  tests after ETL process and need to format the output in standard error messages. What are the standard messages?  Is there such a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ETL is not a standard or a standard process, it is rather a reference to a group of common operations. Since there is no standard there will not be a standard list of messages.